# mean() object not found

Tags: r, mean

I want to get the mean from a variable, but the function `mean()`doesn't find the object.

I have a large dataset. Because I only need to look at some rows, I filtered them out. Now I need to get the mean of a column. But the function doesn't fit the object.

get rows with age =43, sg2 =1 and sg11 =1

`mydata = dat[dat$age == 43 & dat$sg2 ==1 & dat$sg11 ==1,]`

get mean of pp12c

`mean(pp12c, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, data = mydata)`

there comes an error: object 'pp12c' not found

How can i get the `mean()` of the column pp12c with the reduced data set?

Comment: There is no `data` argument in `mean`. Use `$` like you did in your fist line of code. As a general practice, you should read the docs upon getting such error (or prior using the function), see `?mean` in order to see it's arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't knew about the `?mean, I will check it out from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the data frame to the function as well, typically like

```
mean(mydata$pp12c, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Comment: @david Because I copied the OP's code and forgot to remove the erroneous `data` argument. Fixed. Good spot.